# Maximum nodes to visit in a graph for a given cost

Tags: graph, dynamic-programming

I came across a problem in a coding exam where the problem statement goes like below

We have N cities and one 2D array, lets say graph[N+1][N+1].

graph[i][j] represents the cost to go to j from i. It is an undirected graph so graph[i][j]=graph[j][i], where 0<=i,j<=N

Another input parameter is given as 'totalCost' and we have to find the maximum cities we can visit within our total cost from index 0 i.e. i=0.

So the method signature will look like this: public int getMaxCities(int N,int totalCost,int[][] graph);

Any implementation suggestion for this problem in JAVA?
I know it is a combination of 0/1 Knapsack problem and travelling salesman problem but combining both of them seems hard.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that a city cannot visit itself, and that multiple visits do not count. let getMaxnodestartati(int N,int totalCost,int[][] graph_val,int start_i,set visited_nodes) be the maximum number of visits possible starting at position i for matrix graph graph_val, with nodes already visisted in visited_nodes.
Note that:

- N=0, getMaxnodestartati(N,totalCost,graph_val,
  start_i,visited_nodes) =0
- for totalCost<=0,getMaxnodestartati(N,totalCost,graph_val,start_i,visited_nodes) = 0
- that for any graph
  graphvalnew and starting node with neighbors  in graphvalnew:
  neighs=[neigh_1,neigh_2,.... neigh_m] we have the recursive formula:

```
for m in len(neighs): 
    totalcostm = totalCost - graph_val[start_i][neighs[m]]
    val[m] =getMaxnodestartati(N,totalCostm,graph_val,neighs[m],visitedm)
    visits[m]=val[m]+not_ind(neighs[m]],visited_nodes)
return max(visits)
```

where

- `visitedm =Set(visited_nodes).add(neigh_m)`
- not_ind is a function which is 1 if neigh_m is not in visited_nodes and 0 otherwise